# Invoking a sub JSP page while executing a selenium web driver script and validating it

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am executing a script which validates the main screen in an application. In the same application there's a hyperlink which opens a new jsp page. When I try to handle it through webdriver window handle it doesn't recognize the new page opened by the main app.

How to handle such a scenario?

There is some data on the newly opened JSP page which i need to validate as a part of the test case.

Tried window handle, not working. obviously, since its not a pop-up.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to discern exactly what the problem is without you showing the code and what you mean by it not being a pop-up but it being a new window. From what I can interpret, if selenium isn't recognising this as a new window when it is, perhaps it will work if you opened the link in a tab and then switched to that tab. You could do that by:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.keyDown(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL)
    .click(yourHyperlink)
    .keyUp(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL)
    .build()
    .perform();
```

Selenium automatically switches the context to this new tab but even if it doesn't then the window handle will be able to recognise it.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your solution. But it is still opening in a new tab. The Web Driver is still not able to open in a new tab. May be the design of the web page is in such a way that the hyperlink invokes a sub jsp page which has no link of the master page.

Comment: Got the solution. It was the internet explorer settings, protected mode.